# How to detect whether the user is on a specific menu?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, menu, custom-module

I am assigning a php module on different menus on my Joomla website, but I want the module to show different data when loaded on different menu pages.

Example : There is parent menu **Home**  and three sub-menus, **Sub-menu1**, **Sub-menu2** and **Sub-menu3**.

When user browses **sub-menu1** page, the module should load "Welcome to **Sub-menu1**" and when the user is on **sub-menu2** page, the module should load "Welcome to **sub-menu2**" and so on. I have around 200 sub-menu pages on my Joomla website and I don't want to assign 200 individual php modules for them.
I guess it would require an **IF/ELSE condition** but are there any specific ID's allotted to the Joomla menus? If yes, how can I retrieve the data (***menu IDs***) while loading the module and use the IF/ELSE condition?

*P.S* I have already imported the **Joomla CMS** (Joomla 3.4.8) using this :

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/' ));  
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to display the desired message:

```
$app   = JFactory::getApplication(); exist
$menu  = $app->getMenu();
$title = $menu->getActive()->title;

echo 'Welcome to ' . $title;
```

Comment: I had posted an example in my post, I don't need the title name only.
I need to run alot of code for every particular menu, that's why I had mentioned it might require IF/ELSE.

Answer (score 0):

Use the input given to the application that ultimately controls which page is displayed and therefore which sub-menu is shown

This may not be the "Joomla" way to do things I am relatively new to Joomla  anyway use the:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input
```

Object documentation on this JInput object can be found on the Joomla document site but if in doubt there are your standard php debugging tools like

```
var_dump($var)
```